# jqGrid using requireJS - grid loads but does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, requirejs

I'm loading data into a jqGrid through requireJS, the data loads, formats and displays but after which nothing works, sorting, row selecting, paging etc. The grid works perfectly fine if I init the jqGrid without requireJS.

RequireJS config snippet :

```
"jqGrid": "jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid.min",
"grid-locale": "jqGrid/i18n/grid.locale-en", ...
shim: {
  "jqGrid": ["grid-locale", "jquery-ui"]
}
```

JavaScript snippet:

```
define(["jquery", "httpUtils", "jqGrid"],
function ($, httpUtils, jqGrid) {
    window.jqGrid = jqGrid;

    var myViewModel = function () {
        var data = httpUtils.httpSyncGet('xxx');
        var grid = $('#index').jqGrid({
            colNames: ['ClientIdentifier'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'ClientIdentifier', width: "150pt" }
            ],
            datastr: data,
            datatype: 'jsonstring',
            rowNum: 25,
            rownumbers: true,
            height: 500,
            viewrecords: true,
            width: 1100,
            shrinkToFit: false
        });
    };

    return myViewModel;
});
```

Sorry if the code isn't very comprehensive I had to take out snippets from a large project. I'm just curious as to what causes the jqGrid to finish loading, but somehow 'unload' all of it's functions. There is no javascript error in the console as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing some modules and dependencies.  Here's what worked for me (and is also trimmed out from a larger project):

```js
require.config({
    baseUrl: "Scripts/TypeScript",
    paths: {
        jquerygrid: "../jquery.jqGrid.src",
        jqueryui: "../jquery-ui-1.11.4",
        jqgridlocale: "../i18n/grid.locale-en",
        jqgrid: "../jquery.jqGrid.min"
    },
    shim: {
        jqueryui: {
            deps: ["jquery"]
        },
        uigrid: {
            deps: ["jqueryui"]
        },
        jqgrid: {
            deps: ['jqueryui', 'jqgridlocale']
        },
        jqgridlocale: {
            deps: ['jqueryui']
        }
    }
});
```

I adapted the code above from this answer:  [requirejs jquery multiple dependent non module jquery plugins like jquery-ui and jqGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15728329/requirejs-jquery-multiple-dependent-non-module-jquery-plugins-like-jquery-ui-and) , which addresses a more complicated scenario but my also be useful for you.